# How is data stored in an image file

Tags: image

I'm interested on a low level how image data is stored. For example, one can pull up an image in Windows and get information about the image (Camera used, date etc).

On a general level (I'm sure png, jpeg etc differ) do images have some type of header section where properties are defined, and possibly a body section that specifies the color for a specific pixel via a multidimensional array?

What might an image source look like if you could view the source similar to a webpage? If I open up a JPEG on my computer the first few lines look like XML.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats - follow the links in there to any particular format you want to learn about, and check out the "technical details" section on each format's page.

Comment: Images are binary. If you open up a jpeg in a text editor that supports HEX mode you will be able to see the *guts* of it so to speak better as so http://snag.gy/X1b7B.jpg. Also check out EXIF for details on how most cameras store information in the header of jpeg files for example. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format

Comment: When you say binary, the pixel data is binary I'm assuming, but the meta data has got to be stored in some type of key value pair right? And I'm assuming that could xml, so if attempted to interpret the file as ascii text you'll see that key/value pair (xml for example), but the binary pixel data is going to look like jibberish.

Answer (score 2):

The XML you are seeing is part of the [Exchangeable image file format (or Exif)](https://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html).  If you look at the file in a Hex editor you should see markers like these:

> Every JPEG file starts from binary value '0xFFD8', ends by binary
>   value '0xFFD9'. There are several binary 0xFFXX data in JPEG data,
>   they are called as "Marker", and it means the period of JPEG
>   information data. 0xFFD8 means SOI(Start of image), 0xFFD9 means
>   EOI(End of image).

A PNG file will always start with [these eight bytes](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.1/PNG-Rationale.html#R.PNG-file-signature): `0x89  0x50  0x4E  0x47  0x0D  0x0A  0x1A  0x0A`.  It then has a similar mechanism to JPEG of using byte markers to indicate sections of data.  Read the full specification [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/).